# Json to float array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, json, nlohmann-json

If I have an array

```
{"adcMax":[4.7625087616802115e-35,4189.125,-2.6489062679435627e-11,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

And I want to read in `adcMax` as a float array using [`nlohmann`](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) C++ Json library. How can I do that?

I have tried to read the json array and `memcpy` it into my original array

```
std::ifstream calibrationFields;
calibrationFields.open(CALIBRATION_FIELDS_JSON);
if (calibrationFields.is_open()) {
    // Read json
    std::string jsonLine;
    std::getline(calibrationFields, jsonLine);
    nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(jsonLine);

    // Apply into adcMin
    memcpy(adcMax, j["adcMax"].get<std::vector<float>>(), ADC_LENGTH);
```

The problem is that I need to convert this

```
j["adcMax"].get<std::vector<float>>()
```

Into `float[]` array and not `vector<float>` in C++. How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you even bothering with C-style arrays? In 1998 that might have made sense, but these days we have better options.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't know. I'm used to C code, but this is the second project I do with C++.

Comment: `memcpy`? No, not in C++. That's C - `std::copy` is one alternative.

Comment: If you need an array, `vector` has a `data` method that can give you direct access to the `vector`'s internal array.

Comment: So is there any way for me to get the `float[]` array from the array field `adcMax` in my `.json` file?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Just because `memcpy` is from the C lanuage, it doesn't mean that it cannot be used in C++.

Comment: @Heretic Of course not. It's just usually the wrong tool.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ok. But do you know how to get `float[]` array from that `.json` file?

Comment: Part of the reason to learn modern code, you can do: `auto arr = json["adcMax"].get<std::array<double, 12>>();` https://godbolt.org/z/os5qsqxKd

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I understand. I need to start using the C++ features and stop using the C features.